# Nutch 2.3.1 on OSX does not connect to MongoDB

Tags: macos, mongodb, nutch, gora

I configured a local Nutch 2.3.1 instance on MacOS 10.11.5 (El Capitan) running in Eclipse as described here: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse

As data store to use I configured MongoDB 2.6.12 which is also running on my local MacOS machine. I took the Gora config from here: http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/

**ivy.xml**

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-mongodb" rev="0.6.1" conf="*->default" />
```

**gora.properties**

```
gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore
gora.mongodb.override_hadoop_configuration=false
gora.mongodb.mapping.file=/gora-mongodb-mapping.xml
gora.mongodb.servers=localhost:27017
# I tried several server settings like localhost, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:27017, ...
gora.mongodb.db=nutch
```

I did not change **gora-mongodb-mapping.xml**.

**nutch-site.xml**

```
<property>
 <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore</value>
 <description>Default class for storing data</description>
</property>
```

If I run the inject command, **hadoop.log** shows this confusing result:

```
2016-07-12 23:23:16,818 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: starting at 2016-07-12 23:23:16
2016-07-12 23:23:16,819 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /Users/myaccount/Documents/Nutch/urls
2016-07-12 23:23:17,054 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-07-12 23:23:17,416 ERROR store.MongoStore - 
2016-07-12 23:23:17,417 ERROR store.MongoStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4b5189ac
2016-07-12 23:23:17,418 ERROR store.MongoStore - Error while initializing MongoDB store: java.lang.NullPointerException
2016-07-12 23:23:17,419 ERROR crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:267)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:299)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore.initialize(MongoStore.java:131)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoMappingBuilder.fromFile(MongoMappingBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore.initialize(MongoStore.java:118)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoMapping.newDocumentField(MongoMapping.java:109)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoMapping.addClassField(MongoMapping.java:169)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoMappingBuilder.loadPersistentClass(MongoMappingBuilder.java:169)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoMappingBuilder.fromFile(MongoMappingBuilder.java:112)
    ... 10 more
```

After two days I've run out of ideas.

Within the log file I can't identify any valuable hint. The MongoDB logs don't show any connection attempts (not to mention an active connection). Using `mongo` I'm able to connect to the database and requesting http://localhost:27017 shows the expected message (*"It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."*) and corresponding log file entries. If I switch the data store to Cassandra, injecting works as expected, so Nutch itself also seems to work.

**Does anybody know what I'm missing or understand what the hadoop.log is trying to tell me?**

Any help would be appreciated! Thx.

**Update:** I also tried to use this configuration on an Ubuntu 14.04 server - works as expected. So I suppose my issue is related to the connection between Nutch & MongoDB running on a Mac. (If somebody wants to know: I'm trying to get the configuration working on my Mac because I want to do some local development with no need of a server connection.)

Comment: Hi Andre, are you able to figure out this issue? i am getting same on ubuntu-16.04

Comment: No, sorry. As I mentioned above, on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS it works like a charme, so I continue working on the server. If you can find a solution, I would still appreciate a hint. ;-)

Comment: Did you try debugging this in eclipse. I have a feeling that they've added some fields that have not been added to the mongo mapping file.

Comment: Hello Andre, I had a different issue but it turns out that the gora-mongodb 0.6.1 uses an old mongo connector which causes the issue. Try using `<dependency org="org.mongodb" name="mongo-java-driver" rev="2.14.3"/>` in your ivy.xml and recompile nutch and try again.

Comment: Thx for this hint. Currently I don't have a running setup at my Mac, but I will give it a try!

Comment: I don't know if you are still trying to get nutch to crawl with mongodb on your mac. I got mine working using the latest mongodb fo mac:
fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.2.tgz